# Chrome Apps Print Preview opens below main window

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

When I attempt to print from within my Chrome app, the print preview is launching below the app instead of over the app window, like it does in the Chrome web browser.  For smaller apps this works fine, but my app takes up most of the screen so the print preview is offscreen and isn't accessible to the user.  Is there a way to make it launch over the app instead?

This can be reproduced with the sample app "Printest": https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/printing

[image: chrome app print preview is offscreen]

Comment: My guess is that the dialog is being positioned relative to the window it is printing, not relative to what you are calling the "app window." Are you printing the "app window" or some other window? (I've quoted "app window" because Chrome Apps don't have a concept of "app window." They can have zero or more windows, each of which is of equal status.)

Comment: I'm waiting for API for that. Currently this looks disgusting.

Comment: @MarcRochkind There's a webview within the app that's being printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been [fixed](https://crrev.com/4bc9cfaa94d641be10f1979a347ab50f3dea2b6f) in Chrome 40 which is currently in beta-channel.